# how to upgrade from grails 1.2.2 to 1.3.7?

Tags: grails

I tried to upgrade my current project to grails 1.3.7 (from 1.2.2)

I tried to grails upgrade first, and then I tried to update all the plugins. I use ofchart, jsecurity and liquibase.

When I tried to run the grails (with grails run-app)

it won't start the apps instead it shut down. When I checked on my stacktrace.log I found something like this:

> 2011-10-03 11:59:09,250 [main] ERROR StackTrace  - Sanitizing stacktrace:
>   groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer) values: [1800000]
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:54)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:46)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:40)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:124)
>       at BootStrap$_closure1.doCall(BootStrap.groovy:12)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
>       at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1058)
>       at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1070)
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:930)
>       at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1070)
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
>       at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:282)
>       at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:277)

Any idea how to fix this ? Thank you very much.

ps: I'm using latest / newest java.

here is my script for running the app

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m 
grails run-app -Dserver.port=9090 -Ddisable.auto.recompile=false
```

List of plugins:

```
 Plug-ins you currently have installed are listed below:
-------------------------------------------------------------

hibernate           1.3.7            --  Hibernate for Grails
jetty               1.2-SNAPSHOT     --  Jetty Plugin
jsecurity           0.4.1            --  Security support via the JSecurity framework.
ofchart             0.6.3            --  Plugin summary/headline
```

Comment: Do you have anything special at BootStrap.groovy:12?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dataSource` bean is now a proxy for the real datasource. It's an instance of `TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy` which implements the `DataSource` interface, but since it's not the 'real' datasource you can't call non-standard methods on it.

I'm assuming you have a `def dataSource` field - just change it to `def dataSourceUnproxied` and then you can call methods like `setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis()` on it.